# How do I fix issues with zipped Windows-10 Virtual Machine downloaded from Microsoft?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I'm trying to set up a Windows 10 Hyper-V VM.
MicroSoft has a "Developer" VM that comes preloaded with VS 2019.
I downloaded the VM from Microsoft here:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/virtual-machines/

When I attempt to unzip the file, I keep running into errors:

[image: Unzip Error]

I've retried downloading and unzipping several times.

Has anyone tried to download and use the VM?

Did you run into the same issue?

How do I get around this?

Is there somewhere else where I can download this VM from?

Thanks,JohnB

Comment: try to unzip the file with a different zip tool (7zip, WinRAR) and not buildin zip of Explorer

Comment: Tried multiple tools to unzip the compressed file. They all failed with errors. I ended up just biting the bullet, installing Windows 10 from Hyper-V Gallery and purchasing license for Wiindows 10 Enterprise.